# How to call multiple function on button onClick?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a search functionality to search people record in my master page and have implemented custom validator to it. But strangely in some pages it works and for others it displays error message but navigate to second page.

So I am trying to first validate with JavaScript then the code behind function as the website is published and many changes to html & CSS has been done on the published site and making same changes in source code is taking more time. Wanted to know how to call button's onClick function in JS so that first I check in JS if condition is true it calls onClick function else stay back on the same page.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" mouseClick="" ID="SearchButton" Text="Instant Search" OnClick="SearchButton_Click"  />

<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter first name"
            ControlToValidate="firstname" 
            ForeColor="#FF3300" Font-Bold="True" 
            ValidateEmptyText="True" ClientValidationFunction="validateFname"></asp:CustomValidator>


function validateFname(source, arguments) {

            if (arguments.Value != "First Name...") {
                arguments.IsValid = true;
            } else {
                arguments.IsValid = false;
                alert("Please enter First Name")
                return false;
            }

    }
```

Comment: what u have tried ?can u paste your code

Comment: @sharad: I have updated my question with code buddy..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to create a function that calls multiple functions. By doing this, you call a function and that function will call multiple functions.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at these question. It could help you achieve what your trying

[calling asp.net codebehind function from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425797/calling-asp-net-codebehind-function-from-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use onClientClick event to call  Javascript functoion that does validation.

`<asp:Button OnClientClick="validateFname();" runat="server" />`